# Посчитать сумму по годам Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Итак, есть исходный DF:

```
Year    X1
2010    10
2010    15
2010    20
2011    30
2008    50
2008    50
2009    10
2010    10
```

Необходимо посчитать сумму по каждому году (даже если всего 1 значение) и вывести в новый DF. Должно получиться как-то так:

```
Year    Sum
2008    100
2009    10
2010    55
2011    30
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [34]: res = df.groupby('Year', as_index=False)['X1'].sum()

In [35]: res
Out[35]:
   Year   X1
0  2008  100
1  2009   10
2  2010   55
3  2011   30
```